# WebBrowser Control WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs LocalPath

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control, uri

I have the following method to navigate winforms `WebBrowser` Control to `urlString`.

```
private void NavigateToUrl(string urlString)
{
    this.webContainer.Navigate(urlString);
}
```

And I Have  overridden `OnWebPageLoad` method, where I log the `eargs.Url.LocalPath` Property.

```
public override void OnWebPageLoad(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs eargs)
        {

LogMessage(LogFacilityName,
                    String.Format("OnWebPageLoad() : Unknown page was loaded (LocalPath = '{0}').", eargs.Url.LocalPath),
                    LogType.Warning);
}
```

The Problem is that sometimes `eargs.Url.LocalPath` is equal to "/" (single slash).
But As I log url before calling navigation, I know that it is not equal to "/" (single slash) and is one of my html forms.

**Why Should it happen? Any Idea?**
[Here is eargs.Url.LocalPath MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.localpath%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: can you reproduce the request-responce sequence in fiddler? do you see something unexpected there?

Comment: I don't have such a luxury. Just log files to make it clear. software is installed on different computer. (where fiddler mustn't be installed)

Comment: Have you tried AbsolutePath?

Comment: but you can try to reproduce the problem on your computer and catch traffic with fiddler?

Comment: Nope, I can't.  I can't explain exactly how the software(huge monster) works and please trust me. :)
and I want to add that it's rare case